# How to make a regular expression which contains "is not equal to previous group"

Tags: regex

So i have the following regular expression:

`^(.).\1$`

This means that the first character and the last should be the same, and they can be any character. Now consider the following:

BAA This will not match with the regex, which is correct

ASA This will match with the regex, which is correct

AAA This will match with the regex, but i don't want it to be a match

I don't want the regex to match AAA, because I want the second character not to match the first one. So I made this regex:
`^(.)[^\1]\1$`

That regex means
first character: match any
second character: dont match first character
third character: match the first character

But this does not work because the "\1" became a "1" with an escape character. How do I solve this?

Comment: A negative lookahead should work. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41572667/1639625

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^(.)(?!\1).\1$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^           from the start of string
(.)         match and capture any single character
(?!\1).     assert that single following character does NOT match preceding one
\1          match a single character identical to first one
$           end of string
```

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Comment: Just wanted to suggest the same, but I think the `(?:...)` is not necessary. Also, why not add the other "should (not) match" examples in the link?

Comment: This is what he meant: ^(.)(?!\1).\1$, the second character doesn't need a group

Answer (score 2):

How about the use of negative  lookahead:

```
^(.)(?!\1).\1$
```